# Significant performance loss when I return a new array

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have the following code.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items"></div>
```

This one renders quickly. Then I did this:

```
getItems() {
    return this.items;
}

<div *ngFor="let item of getItems()"></div>
```

This is also performant. However, this one:

```
getItems() {
    return this.items.filter(item => item.premium === true);
}

<div *ngFor="let item of getItems()"></div>
```

runs very slow. Any ideas how I can improve the performance of filtering logic and why I have a big performance loss returning a new array?

Comment: when you are doing this `<div *ngFor="let item of getItems()"></div>` it calls the function when ever changeDetection happen that's why there is a significant performance loss

Comment: what is the length of items ?

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha I think it is irrelevant. :)

Comment: @YashRami What would be the proper solution?

Comment: Keep a variable for `premiumItems`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this

1> If your array change every second or every min then use `trackBy` so it change only that DOM element whose value change

**html**

```
<div *ngFor="let data of myArray; trackBy: trackFunction" >
            {{data}}
</div>
```

**TS**

```
trackFunction(index, data) {
   if (!data) return null;
   return data
}
```

2> you can also directly subscribe that array by using a `async` pipe

**TS**

```
apiCall() {
  this.myArray = this.service.getData(); // here this service return the observable 
}
```

***HTML***

```
<div *ngFor="let data of myArray | async"> 
{{data}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

getItems() function  returns a new array every time it's called so as result the *ngFor loop is running every ngDoCheck lifecycle and the whole content is re-rendered. you need to keep the same reference to the returned array, so as a solution you can call this function once when initializing your component and keep the result inside a variable and use it after that.